# Randomly Grouping TableView data in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xcode6

I want to divide the cells in groups as per condition but i am getting repeated values where i am wrong.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 5;
    }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if(section == 0)
        {
            return 1;     
        }
        else if(section == 1)
            {
                return 6;
            }
        else if(section ==2)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
         return [arrControls count]-9;
        }    
    }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [arrControls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: you have to use different array's for each section

Comment: sam please explain how can i use different arrays . i made only one murtable array. How can i break it based on sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `array` of `NSMutableArray`s for each section.

```
NSMutableArray *arrays[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
{
    arrays[i] = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
[arrays[0] addObject:@"add Your objects in section 0"];
[arrays[1] addObject:@"add Your objects in section 1"];
[arrays[2] addObject:@"add Your objects in section 2"];
```

etc..

Then.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   array[section].count
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [array[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate your question a little bit. Its hard to understand what exactly your problem is.

In case you are using xib or storyboard for tableCell use this approach 1:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";

MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (MyCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

In case you are not using storyboard for cell try this approach 2:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

[cell setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/triffort.com/file/d/0B__F6yL7OYWCbU41c0hvWGVZNGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i have zipped the file ..have a look where it is wrong

Comment: @Dalvik. You need different array for each section. And you already have only one mutableArray. Here is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath  , u need to return different cells for different section 
Let say u have the 3 custom classes( with inferface for all of them ) inherited from UITableViewCell

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
    if(inderPath.Section ==0 )
            {
        //assuing that custom class name is detailTableViewCell.h and interface file name is same .
           static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @detailTableViewCell ;
           detailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]
            if(cell == nil )
            {
              NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"detailTableViewCell" ownder self options:nil];
             cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0]

            }

     return cell   ;
    }
    if(inderPath.Section ==1 )
    {
    similarly for another subclass of UItableViewCell ;
    }
  if(inderPath.Section ==2 )
    {
    similarly for another subclass of UItableViewCell ;
    }
    // one common cell for other sections
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell.textLabel.text = [arrControls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this`
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1)
{
  cell.textLabel.text = [secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 2)
{
 cell.textLabel.text = [thirdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 3)
{
  cell.textLabel.text = [thirdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else 
{
 cell.textLabel.text = [FourthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
  return cell;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

@Dalvik. You need different array for each section. And you already have only one mutableArray.

You can take the array where each object in array will give you array for the rows.

The format of data you can use is as follows

(
     {key : Array},
     {key : Array},
     {key : Array},
     {key : Array},
)

or simply

(
     (Array),
     (Array),
)

inside, numberOfRowsInSection: you can access it using
{
     return [[[dataArray objectAtIndex:section]ObjectFoyKey:key]count];

```
 or

 return [[dataarray objectAtIndex:section]count];
```

}

inside,  cellFOrRowAtIndexPath: you can access it using
{

```
 array =  [[dataArray objectAtIndex:section]ObjectFoyKey:key];
 cell.textlabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 or

 array =  [dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
 cell.textlabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

}

Hope this will help you..